# Can I fingering my husband anal?

Tags: sex, husband-wife, physical-contact, intercourse

I am a married women. During physical intercourse I have fingering my husband anal. Is it permissable? And also can I put sex toy in my husband anal?

Comment: I have no knowledge about this very situation. However, it is clear that you and your husband are allowed to enjoy your sexual intimacy in every way possible. Except, sex during a period or anal sex. Since fingering doesn't constitute anal sex...I don't think it's going to be a problem. Although don't take my word for it...

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu'alaykum wa rahmatullahi wa barakatuh.

I will try to answer this question to the best of my knowledge insha'Allah.

Firstly, it is established by the consensus that anal sex is haram; the definition of "anal sex" may be inferred as the penetration of the penis (or equivalent) into the anal passage. Thus, although it may be suggested that a finger is not a penis, however, the overall effect [of insertion] can be deduced as equivalent; the same can be said for any other foreign objects (such as "sex toys").

Overall, from my research, as well as some deduction: in the same way that penetration in the anus is unlawful, sticking any other foreign objects into the anus [as an alternative] is also **impermissible**.

However, although I am confident about this legislation, I would like to highlight that I am no scholar.

Nonetheless, this is something that should definitely be avoided.

Jazak'Allak Khayrun.